# Button on-click scrolling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

quite new to coding with javascript and such, having an issue with an on-click scroll where it goes to another div. I've checked a lot of the posts on here but can't seem to find out why it won't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! It's probably a simple fix that I just don't have the experience to be able to notice..

Here's the code (I'll try to condense it but imagine there's a lot of content in between so it's actually worth scrolling to)

HTML

```
 <div class="button-div"><button type="button">Click here</button></div>
 <div class="div-2-under-top">Content here</div>
```

Jscript

```
 $("button").click(function() {
   $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".div-2-under-top").offset().top},
      'slow')
 })
```

I have the latest jquery V3.3.1 so I wouldn't think that would be the issue... any ideas?

Here's a picture of the actual code itself in-case there's something important I missed (apologies if the code is dirty)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not able to replicate your issue. I've copy+pasted your code and added a simple margin to simulate a long page: http://jsfiddle.net/Lo04hg7c/ - as you can see, it works just fine. Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: That's the thing, I can get it to work in jsfiddle, just not in my own code which is why I'm so confused..I've been messing around with it for about an hour now. Edit: Can't see any errors in console.

Comment: @TylerRoper Looks like you've found the answer!

Comment: @JonathanLam Yep! Removed my comment to clarify after seeing the screenshot. OP, your button click event needs to be *inside* of the `$(function() { ... })` section. This section will be executed *after waiting for the page to load*. By trying to attach an event to `$("button")` *outside* of this, the `button` has not loaded yet, so the event can't be attached.

Comment: @TylerRoper Thank you! This fixed the issue! Appreciate the help a lot! I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: Glad to have helped. As a note, `$(function() { ... })` is *shorthand* for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`, which more accurately describes *"Anything in this function will wait for the page to load before executing"*.

Comment: Good to know, I'm very new to coding in general (Only been learning around a week, so there's a lot of issues and such that come up) but with this site I'm learning a lot in a short amount of time! Looking forward to being the one who helps in the future.

Comment: you can't expect it to scroll down if it don't have something to scroll or the content height doesn't exceed to its container

Comment: @Beginner OP had mentioned this in his question: *"I'll try to condense it but imagine there's a lot of content in between so it's actually worth scrolling to"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TylerRoper found the answer for me.

I'll paste his answer here in-case anyone stumbles across this and is looking for the answer.

> OP, your button click event needs to be inside of the $(function() { ... }) section. This section will be executed after waiting for the page to load. By trying to attach an event to $("button") outside of this, the button has not loaded yet, so the event can't be attached.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("button").click(function() {
               $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $(".div-2-under-top").offset().top},
                  1000);
             });
```

Try see can work or not ? hope this help you